# Disable Link Until Input and Select Fields Have Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am looking to make sure all the dropdown fields have a selected value and input fields have a value. How could I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
validate();
$('input').on('keyup', validate);
});

function validate() {
var inputsWithValues = 0;
var myInputs = $("input:not([type='hidden'])");

myInputs.each(function(e) {
// if it has a value, increment the counter
if ($(this).val()) {
  inputsWithValues += 1;
}
});

if (inputsWithValues == myInputs.length) {
$(“.button_link").removeClass('disabled').addAttr("href"); 
} else {
$(“.button_link").addClass('disabled').removeAttr("href");
}
}
```

I am looking to see how I can detect both input fields and selects?  My code works just not on selects.

var myInputs = $("input:not([type='hidden'])");

(selects)???

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. You need to bear in mind a few things though. dropdowns are not inputs they are selects. also on an input checking for $(this).val() will always be true. Perhaps you mean $(this).val() != ""

Comment: I am pretty much stuck, I have tried hours but got nada.  How do I check to make sure that Select also has a value along with input fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got this working, if anyone has any tweaks to it please let me know.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
validate();
$('input').on('keyup', validate);
$('select').on('change', validate);
});

function validate() {
var inputsWithValues = 0;

// get all input fields except for type='submit'
// var myInputs = $("input:not([type='submit'])");
var myInputs = $("option:selected, input:not([type='hidden'])");

myInputs.each(function(e) {
// if it has a value, increment the counter
if ($(this).val()) {
  inputsWithValues += 1;
}
});

if (inputsWithValues == myInputs.length) {
$(".button_link").removeClass('disabled').addAttr("href"); 
} else {
$(".button_link").addClass('disabled').removeAttr("href");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. You may need to tweak it a little.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //validate();
    $('input').on('blur', function(){
        if(validate()){
            $(".button_link").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(".button_link").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        if(validate()){
            $(".button_link").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $(".button_link").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});

function validate() {
    $("input:not([type='hidden'],[type='button'])").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("select").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){ // change empty string if unselected has a value (e.g. 0)
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where to start with this regarding tweaking.  I placed it in and it does not disable the buttons or seem to work.

Comment: It's got 2 missing ).  I don't know how to locate where they are suppose to go, I am not a programmer and trying to grasp it but nada.

Comment: 2 what missing? Can you post your HTML code too? that might help

Comment: It's your code above that is missing the right parenthesis. My code seems to debug fine, it does not work with Select.

Comment: What type of element is .button_link referring to? BTW there is no addAttr() function. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I am trying to disable a link on the page (.button_link) until all input fields are filled out and all the dropdown fields have been selected.

Comment: That code is validating now, thanks.  Unfortunately the form is still not working.  The old code would disable the button until all the text fields got filled in.  Now it's not disabled all the time.